# Why is there a list after the covariance function for numpy?

Tags: numpy

Whenever I'm finding covariance of 2 arrays, I've always seen it done like
(np.cov(X,Y)[0,1])

What purpose does the [0,1] serve?

Comment: Looks like it's indexing the result of the `cov` call, which probably is a 2d numpy array.  Does `cov` docs support this?

Comment: The out variable for `np.cov` is: `The covariance matrix of the variables.`. `np.cov(X,Y)[0,1]` selects one element,first row, 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two 1d arrays `x` and `y`, `np.cov(x, y)` returns:

```
np.array([[variance(x),      covariance(x, y)],
          [covariance(y, x), variance(y)     ]])
```

Thus for the covariance, you need the [0,1] term.

When formulated as `cov(x ,y)`, `numpy` creates `np.cov(X)` where `X = np.stack(x, y, axis = 1)`

The confusion occurs because for `np.cov(X)` is really optimized for many vectors at once, with `X.shape = (m, n)`, and `np.cov(X)[i,j]`, `i, j < n` to be the covariance between rows `i` and `j`.  And the covariance of rows `i` and `i` is just the variance of row `i`.